# selecting controls from flowlayoutpanel in vb.net2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i m using flowlayout panel to dynimacally create pictureboxes on the widows form. My actual problem is that, i want to see specific image in picturebox when user clicks on the item in flow layout panel using click event..

I hade tried some code, but everytime i failed..please help.please suggest me my missing code with some details so i can understand it very well.

### My code is -------------------------------------------------------

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        ' Style Explorer - Thubnail Viewer
        ' FlowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()

        Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog

        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*"

        OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Photos"


        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            For Each file As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                Dim imageControl As New PictureBox()
                imageControl.Name = "pic" & i.ToString()
                imageControl.Height = 100
                imageControl.Width = 100

                Dim myCallback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf ThumbnailCallback)
                Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(file)
                Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(96, 96, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
                imageControl.Image = myThumbnail
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(imageControl)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Function ThumbnailCallback() As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: Use the Tag property of the PictureBox to store the filename. When user clicks the PictureBox, retrieve the Tag and show the image from the file

Comment: Fairly hard to guess what "i want to see specific image" might mean.

Comment: i mean when i click on any image in flow layout panel(using open dialog), this image will be shown in the picturebox(which is created at desin time).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop that add the pictureboxes to the FlowLayoutPanel you could add the name of the file to the Tag property of the dinamically created PictureBox and add an event handler for the click event

```
    For Each file As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        Dim imageControl As New PictureBox()
        imageControl.Name = "pic" & i.ToString()
        imageControl.Height = 100
        imageControl.Width = 100

        ' Save the file from which you create the thumbnail
        imageControl.Tag = file
        ' Set an event handler for the clickevent on the thumbnail
        AddHandler imageControl.Click, AddressOf picClicked

        .....
    Next
```

Now write the event handler that responds to the click event

```
Private Sub picClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim pic = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Control)

    ' The name of the file is in the Tag property....
    Console.WriteLine(pic.Tag.ToString())

    ' Now its your job to display the image knowing the filename
End Sub
```